# Can a great improvement (ex: Manufactory) be removed by automated workers?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

While playing a game, I rushed getting a Great Engineer in order to produce an early [Manufactory](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Manufactory_%28Civ5%29).  A few turns later, I noticed the square had changed back to a farm.

Is it possible my automated workers decided it was better to have food over production, and removed my Manufactory?

Comment: Perhaps this question could be made more general to include any great person improvement? You can keep you manufactury example, but the answer should be general enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In the future, you should turn on the option "automatic workers leave old improvements" in the options, which will prevent issues like this from happening

Comment: While it may be possible, I certainly have never seen it happen in the many games I've played...

Comment: @DanRasmussen Neither have I (I always have leave old improvements on), but it apparently happened to the asker. Given the general incompetence of the worker AI I think what the asker proposes is probably what happened. After seeing the worker AI walk back and forth between 2 cities without ever working, I have learned that it is unwise to underestimate their incompetence.

Comment: I managed to get the manufactury extremely early in the game; maybe that had something to do with it?

Comment: @Toast its more likely to be related to a lack of high-food tiles in general, but putting workers on "leave old improvements" has pretty much 0 downsides. They actually will replace improvements when new resources are discovered (think mining aluminum) and you can always take manual control when needed